# Is there any results for almost sure convergence for Gradient Boosting

Tags: convergence-divergence, machine-learning

This article "[Consistency for L2 Boosting and Matching Pursuit with Trees and Tree-type Basis Functions](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjx0KvP2tDiAhVBq1kKHd26C5gQFjAAegQIAhAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.579.3542%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&usg=AOvVaw2srbq10oqG2DPv1dWv7g42)" from Buhlmann has some results on consistency for Boosting but they are for convergence in probability. I wonder if there are similar results for almost sure convergence.

The reason I am asking this is that I am doing some calculations that depend on these results but convergence in probability is not enough because at some point I need to evoke the dominated convergence theorem to exchange a limit with an integral and I can not do that unless I have almost sure results.

Thanks!